# Postgresql time between changes in boolean column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with four columns; ID, timestamp, event_name and changed_to(boolean).

I need to know how i can get the epoch between to 'timstamps' where 'changed_to' changes from true to false given the 'event_name' is e_DrvMotorStartUp, as an example.

```
id    timestamp                   event_name          changed_to
56682 2015-04-14 09:06:21.93022   e_DrvMotorStartUp  t
56683 2015-04-14 09:06:24.928389  e_DrvMotorRun      t
56684 2015-04-14 09:06:24.928389  e_DrvMotorStartUp  f
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [LATERAL JOIN](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

```
SELECT e.*, e2.*, e."timestamp" - e2."timestamp"
FROM tbl AS e
,LATERAL (SELECT *
          FROM tbl
          WHERE tbl.event_name = e.event_name
                AND e."timestamp" > tbl."timestamp"
                AND tbl.changed_to = 't'
          ORDER BY tbl."timestamp" DESC
          LIMIT 1)
WHERE e.changed_to = 'f'
```

Comment: How will this be for my example above?

Comment: @olem: Come again? I'm not really sure what do you mean by that.